# The incoming request has too many parameters. The server supports a maximum of 2100 parameters.?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, linq

The incoming request has too many parameters. The server supports a maximum of 2100 parameters. Reduce the number of parameters and resend the request.
 code:

query = query.Where(x => !rejected.Contains(x.ApplicationId) && x.Id > minvalue);

here rejected is a list of int type.

it is working fine when i have records upto 700 in rejected list.But after that it start givng me error of sql 2100 parameters.

Comment: I suppose each record has 3 fields.... 700 x 3 = 2.100

Comment: It looks like there is more to the `query` that you are building.  Can you show the rest as I'm guessing you might be using that collection more than once (maybe 3 times?).  Also how do you populate `rejected`?  If it's based on values in the DB then you can use those instead of a list of ids to filter rejected items.

Comment: How many items you have in `rejected` collection? Maximum mumber of parameters supported by SQL query is 2100. So you need to check if `rejected` collection has more than 2100 items. If yes then you should break it down to chunks of 2100 items and execute separate queries using each chunk.

Comment: rejected in your case is a list that has more than 2100 items. If the Rejected is a db table than don't do ToList on it.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya Separate queries wouldn't work here since the OP is doing NOT contains.  That means that each query you break it down into would include all the desired records, plus some of the ones filtered from other queries, resulting in more records than what is in the entire table.  That method would work if it was just contains.

Comment: Even if you make it work for up to 2100 items, it is bad and non scalable design anyway. Do not use linq and Contains in this case, use different approach. TVP is the best option here.

Comment: Can you create a staging table that will iterate thru and store ApplicationID, then have your query based on the staging table?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya i have tried this .i made the two chunks of the rejected list the first chunk was working well but on second chunk i got the same error.

Comment: @NicolaLepetit No....it has only one field.

Comment: @FlorimMaxhuni No rejected is a list where i am only containing Id's and i have only 1000 items in this list

Comment: @AntonínLejsek Actually i wanna make it fast as i can beacause i have bulk data here which i have to process.

Comment: @juharr query containing filtered  records from the table and it is queryable and rejected is the list where i am i only storing id's and using only once and rejected has only 1000 records.

Comment: If you have only 1000 items in the `rejected` list then you will never get this error. Can you share the code of chunk approach?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya i have edit the post please check the code now

Comment: What is the value of `rejected.Count` in `if (rejected.Count > 0)`? And what is the value of `totalUnusedRecords`?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya In current case value of total totalunusedRecords is 1837 and record.count() is 1000